# hide css3 multiline ellipsis read more link when there is no use

Tags: javascript, css, less, multiline, ellipsis

I have a little problem. I figured out a way to use cross-browser multiline ellipsis.

Here is my less CSS mixin.

As you can see, this version works perfect in *webkit* and "ok" in all other browsers.

```
.ellipsis-multi(@lh, @l, @mw) {
  /* non-webkit */
  max-height: @lh*@l;
  /* webkit */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: @l;
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-height: @lh;
  max-width: @mw;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.excerpt {      
  &.hide {
    .ellipsis-multi(1.4em, 3, 100%)
  }
}
```

My problem is, I use a read-more link to add and remove the class "hide". This works perfect, but the link is also visible if the excerpt div only has 2 lines of text.

I need a way to just show the link if the ellipsis is needed.

Here is a Codepen example
http://codepen.io/janwagner/pen/ubHef

I would prefer a CSS only way to fix this :)

Comment: There is no way for CSS to know how many lines of text are displaying, so I can tell you right now that a CSS only solution is not possible. Some type of scripting is going to need to be involved, so I suggest you add some of those tags to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can do this with CSS only. However, you can use the following function to count the number of lines you have:

```
var divHeight = $('.excerpt p').height();
var x = ('.excerpt p').css('line-height');
lineHeight = parseInt(x); // Returns clean line-height
var lines = divHeight / lineHeight; // Returns number of lines
```

And then simply use an if statement to either show or hide the read more button depending on how many lines the paragraph has. Something like this:

```
if(lines > 4){
$('.readmore').show;
}else{
$('.readmore').hide;
}
```

Comment: If you believe this is the right answer marked it as so for future visitors. I am glad I helped.